# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Serving Django Project on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, firewall

I am serving Django Project on Digitalocean Ubuntu Droplet. When I am configure https connection everything collapse and I can nat browse my ip
*188.166.117.124*
On every browser I get **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** error

```
$ grep server_name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* -RiI

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:   server_name _;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:#  server_name example.com;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/personal_web_site:   server_name 188.166.117.124;
```

---

```
$ netstat -tlpdn

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               listen      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               listen      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               listen      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               listen      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    listen      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    listen      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    listen      -
```

---

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :80

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               listen      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    listen      -
```

**strong text**

```
$ sudo ufw status

to                         action       from
-----                      -----       --------
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I tried with `$ sudo ufw disabled` nothing changed
What is the problem of my server

Comment: You're talking abouth HTTPS, but I can't see anything listening on port 443 in the `netstat` output. Are you sure you've configured your nginx correctly?

Comment: 443 is in the Nginx HTTPS  and it is open. But now I can not browse with http (port 80) either.

Comment: It's open in your firewall, but nginx is clearly not configured properly to use it as it is not listening on that. Check you nginx configuration.